# Retain or delete parts of textstring in tweets

Tags: string-manipulation, regular-expressions

For a twitter analysis I collected many tweets. For example:

```
tweet = "Designing interventions for food security and prevention of \
malnutrition in Bangladesh #sensemaker http://t.co/wulTxX3vVK"
```

In several of these tweets  there is a textstring "http://t.co/wulTxX3vVK". What they all have in commen is the first part "http://t.co/". When I use the next code:

```
Flatten[StringCases[ToLowerCase[tweet], RegularExpression["\\w(?<!\\d)[\\w'-]*"]]]
```

The output is

> {"designing", "interventions", "for", "food", "security", "and", 
>   "prevention", "of", "malnutrition", "in", "bangladesh", "sensemaker", 
>   "http", "t", "co", "wultxx3vvk"}

What is the best way to retain (or delete) al parts that start with "http://t.co/-------"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a complement to @MikeHoneychurch, a pure `RegularExpression` solution:

```
    tweet2 = "Designing interventions for food security and prevention of
malnutrition in Bangladesh #sensemaker http://t.co/wulTxX3vVK and some other stuff"

StringReplace[tweet2, RegularExpression["http://t.co/.+?\\b"] :> ""]
```

or, to remove additional spaces:

```
StringReplace[tweet2, RegularExpression["http://t.co/.+?\\b *"] :> ""]
```

Answer (score 2):

If the link is always at the end you could do something like:

```
StringReplace[tweet, "http://t.co/" ~~ __ ~~ EndOfString :> ""]
```

if not then try

```
tweet2 = "Designing interventions for food security and prevention of
malnutrition in Bangladesh #sensemaker http://t.co/wulTxX3vVK and some other stuff"

StringReplace[tweet2,Shortest["http://t.co/" ~~ __ ~~ WhitespaceCharacter] :> ""]
```

Comment: Thanks, Your first comment works fine. The second suggestion gives the following output: "Designing interventions for food security and prevention of malnutrition in Bangladesh #sensemaker stuff". What happend with the string 'and some other'?

Comment: See edit which address the problem you saw. There will be times in your pattern matching that you need to match the shortest pattern or longest pattern.

Comment: Hi Mike,Thanks!